# Stop Mission Control sending full screen windows beyond the furthest desktop

Tags: macos, mission-control, fullscreen

Whenever a window is commanded to become full screen, Mission Control sends it to the right of the rightmost desktop. I find this cumbersome for my workflow, I'd prefer the window to become full screen and to be just at the next right desktop spot of the active desktop. Can this behavior be configured somehow?

Comment: I wish you luck, but I don't think it's possible. The alternative would be to use Maximised & hide the menu bar, then you can put them where you like.

Comment: I _have_ seen this in someone else's Mac (as far as I know, it just came that way), but can't get it to work on my own! (: